# Trying to use a subquery to find two things from two different tables

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to find the book code and book title for each book found in branch number 2 and written by author 20.

the book code and title are found in the "book" table
branch number is found in the 'branch' table 
the "author" table has the author number
theres also a table called 'inventory' that has book code and branch number

any help would be greatful!

This is what I tried:
SELECT BOOK_CODE, TITLE
FROM BOOK
WHERE BOOK_CODE IN
    (SELECT BOOK_CODE
    FROM INVENTORY
    WHERE BRANCH_NUM = '2'
    AND AUTHOR_NUM = '20');

Comment: Please show your tables, and your query attempt(s) or you will quickly find the question downvoted / closed by other Stack Overflow users. Not being nasty, just heads-up. No downvote by me as you are new.

Comment: at least give the table structure....

Answer (score 0):

I have to make a few assumptions about your data structure, but to me, it sounds like what you want is something like this:

```
SELECT book.code, book.title
FROM inventory
INNER JOIN book ON (inventory.book_id = book.code)
WHERE inventory.branch_id = 2 AND inventory.author_id = 20
```

Please let me know if that covers your needs, and if not, I can try again if you supply some more details on the data structure.

// Regards, Morten

Comment: That helps a lot. The problem is the book.code part. it lists it as an unknown column. i'd say i didn't describe my table to well to you.

the book code would be selected from the book table
the title would be selected from the book table
the author number would be selected from the author table
and the branch number is found in the inventory page.

does this help at all? :/